# Why does the runtime seems too long?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime

I am trying to run my code below in Jupyter notebook, but the run time seems endless and then my laptop suddenly hangs. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code? (here, for better understanding, I made the data very smaller)

```
customers = [1,2,3]
nodes = [3,5,6,8,10,14,18]
edges = [(3,6),(8,18),(8,3),(8,10),(8,7),(14,3),(14,5),(14,7),(18,3),(18,8),(18,14)]
demands = {1:200, 2:300, 3:500}
origins = {1:18, 2:8, 3:14}
destinations = {1:6, 2:10, 3:5}
prio_start = {1: [3, 7, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6], 2: [6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5]}

y_set_init = []
dict_path_nodes = {}
for k in customers:
    currentnode = origins[k]    
    path_nodes = [currentnode]       
    path_edges = []
    prio_init = prio_start[k]
    
    stop = False
    while not stop:
        for (e, g) in edges:
            if e == currentnode:
                max_value = max(prio_init)
                max_index = prio_init.index(max_value) + 1
                nextnode = max_index 
                path_nodes.append(nextnode)
                path_edges.append((currentnode, nextnode))
                if (currentnode, nextnode) not in y_set_init:
                     y_set_init.append((currentnode, nextnode))
                currentnode = nextnode
                if currentnode == destinations[k]:
                    stop = True
    dict_path_nodes[k]= path_nodes
print(dict_path_nodes)
```

Is it possible that I miss some "break" for the loops?

Comment: Have you considered to add some debug prints to see what's actually happens?

Comment: @KlausD. Hi Klaus. I am new beginner in coding with python, and I don't know how to do debug prints. I will search for that. Thank you

Comment: Add some useful `print()` statements that show you what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If currentnode = 2, the loop becomes infinite (because e never equals 2). And currentnode may be 2, because it is set as an index of prios, not as they value? Please verify your logic, probably you wanted to get value of this list somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out that I had logical problem in defining valid max_index.